# VS Code - How to run unchanged c++ files without building them again

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-code

I've managed to configure vs code to build and run c++ files using tutorials on their official website and it worked fine, but it *rebuilds* the files every time I hit F5 even if the files were unchanged.

What I want is to run the unchanged files without rebuild them.
I tried to write another task to "just-run-without-rebuild" but didn't know how to switch between this task and the build task, I searched the internet but no solutions.

my task.json is this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": ["-std=c++11", "starter.cpp"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and launch.json is:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "externalConsole": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So basically the "preLaunchTask" is running the "build" task every time it runs, but I want something like this:

```
if (cpp_file is unchanged) then
      "preLaunchTask" : None
else
      "preLaunchTask" : "build"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's for your build-system to determine, not VS Code. I.e. you can use CMake integration.

Comment: Thank you @DanM. I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

What I did was assign the 'F4' key for Run Task, then the 'F5' key for Run Without Debugging and the 'Ctrl + F5' key combination for Start Debugging.

My tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++",
            "command": "C:\\Users\\Kamat\\Desktop\\Programacion\\C++\\Compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Users\\Kamat\\Desktop\\Programacion\\C++\\Compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": null
        }
    ]
}
```

If you find a way to do this process automatically let me know, thank you.

I'm still a beginner at this and I can make some mistakes, but this worked well for me, I hope it works for you too.